# Quarkus Apache Thrift RPC

Tags: quarkus, thrift-protocol

I'm trying to build a microservice using quarkus that uses thrift as the communication protocol. I'm still fairly new to Apache Thrift and Quarkus.
Is there a way to implement a thrift server without the need to migrate over to gRPC?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Thrift is a complete RPC (remote procedure call) system. You can build clients and servers using just Apache Thrift in a wide range of languages and any Thrift client can call any Thrift server hosting the desired service interface regardless of language/platform. You can find tutorials for each of the supported languages here: https://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/

The Apache Software Foundation hosted Thrift project and the CNCF hosted gRPC project are competing RPC systems and do not inter-operator or share code.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. After doing some reading around Apache Thrift in the link you provided and looking at the examples, I was finally able to get it working.